# What is ROS sensor_msgs::Image::Ptr? Is this a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, ros

I am reading some C++ ROS code and I found

```
sensor_msgs::Image::Ptr something(new sensor_msgs());
```

this refers to the ROS type [sensor_msgs/Image Message](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html)

So this is a *Ptr* for the ROS type sensor_msgs/Image Message

What is this ::Ptr ? I suspect it has something to do with smart pointers but I know the smart pointers weak_ptr, shared_ptr and unique_ptr. I don't know this Ptr. Is this standard C++ or something related with ROS? (I suspect not because OpenCV also has Ptr's)

Comment: It is the pointer for ROS message. There should also be `::ConstPtr` if I am not wrong.

Comment: Possible answer here? https://answers.ros.org/question/334163/ptr-suffix-in-ros-messages/

Comment: Are these all ROS exclusive concepts?

Answer (score 2):

> The Ptr/ConstPtr are defined by the ROS message generation and are boost shared pointers.

Source: https://answers.ros.org/question/78741/message-vs-messageptr/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the link I found that

> the XXX::YYY::Ptr is actually a boost::shared_ptr<XXX::YYY> not a
> simple C++ pointer. A Boost shared pointer is a smart pointer
> container that ensures memory will always deleted when no more
> references to the object exist. You can read more about these
> [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)